# C++ dylib in Swift project - undefined symbols for function exposed in dylib

Tags: swift, xcode, dylib

C++ dylib exposes as follows

```
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) int addNumber(int number) {
    return 0;
}
```

in my Swift project, I set the Import Paths dir to the dir containing my module.map file:

```
module MyLib {
    header "myLib.h"
    export *
}
```

I manually add `myLib.h` to my project:

```
#ifndef mylib_h
#define mylib_h

int addNumber(int number);

#endif
```

My `main.swift` does the following:

```
import Foundation
import MyLib

print("Hello, World!")
var result = addNumber(3)
```

When I compile the swift project, I can see that it links against my dylib (-lMyLib), but I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_addNumber", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

So although it's linking correctly, it can't find the symbols.
I've verified both with `nm` (0000000000000d00 (__TEXT,__text) external addNumber) and Hopper that this function does exist in the dylib.

Comment: Did you mark the function with `extern "C"` for C linkage?

Comment: @MartinR that solved the compile issue. Thanks! Now there's a runtime issue :) will update

Comment: @MartinR yep, once adding a "copy" phase of the dylib post-build, everything seems to be working. Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ library, your function must be marked with `extern "C"`
for C linkage:

```
extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) int addNumber(int number) {
    return 0;
}
```

so that the compiler does not mangle the exported name. Swift can only
call C functions, not C++ functions.

See also [What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c).