# Swift and C++ bridging in Xcode

Tags: c++, swift, xcode

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmpWZ.png) 
Machine info:
  macOS 10.13.5
  Xcode 9.4
  Swift 4.1
  Default c++ compiler

I've created simple swift project and just added c++ file with header to it and Xcode created bridging header for me. I've initialised basic function in .cpp file, written prototype to .hpp file and included .hpp file in bridging header. When I've started typing in .swift file everything seemed to work: my cpp function name was suggested in .swift file in proper place and there were no warnings or errors. But, when I've tried to build this project, and got following: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_get", referenced from:
      _main in main.o

Here is source code:

```
    // main.swift
    import Foundation

    print("Hello, World!")

    var number = get();

    // cppBackend.cpp
    int get()
        {
        return 1;
        }

    // cppBackend.hpp
    int get();

    // test-Bridging-Header.h
    #include "cppBackend.hpp"


    //cppBackend.hpp second version
    #ifdef _cplusplus
    extern "C"
        {
    #endif


    #include <stdio.h>

    int get();

    #ifdef _cplusplu
        }
    #endif
```

Comment: Xcode can bridge it: https://youtu.be/0x6JbiphNS4

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49406606/1187415: you have do disable "name mangling" with `extern "C"`

Comment: I mean, it is possible to use both in one project, not file.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But I've already tried it and got the same error.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: #ifdef _cplusplus
        extern "C"
            {
        #endif


        #include <stdio.h>

        int get();

        #ifdef _cplusplu
            }
        #endif

Comment: Did you add extern "C" declaration also in the .cpp file (or do you include the .hpp file from the .cpp file) ?

Comment: I've included .hpp file from the .cpp one

Comment: It should be `#ifdef __cplusplus`, with *two* underscore characters.

Comment: OMG, that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently an interop between Swift and C++. You can easily do ObjC and C, but for C++ you're going to wrap your C++ code in ObjC.

Comment: Hmm, but what about this: https://youtu.be/0x6JbiphNS4

Comment: He wasn't including the `.hpp` in the bridging header. He wrapped the C++ code in a C function and instead included a `.h` in the briding header and added the extern C in the wrapper.

Comment: I've tried that also. Same error.

Comment: Your code example doesn't indicate this. It still shows a `.hpp` being included in the bridging header.

Comment: Sorry. Problem is already solved. Thanks for your assistance.